# Gmail: This message seems dangerous

Tags: email, gmail

Ok, I am working on an invite system for my work, the invite system sends an email to the recipient with a link containing a unique token allowing them to sign up.

The issue is, now that I am actually testing it, the emails are marked as "This message seems dangerous" by gmail, This looks really bad for the company. I have not been able to find any information on what triggers this.

[image: The error message]

The email is being sent via office365(SMTP) as that is what our email is set up with to try and avoid this kind of thing.

I have seen comments online that it may be due to the token link, If so, how else am I meant to do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaImTo It is programming related, something in what I have programmed is being interpreted as suspicious by gmail. I need to find out what it is so no one else sees this warning.

Comment: You need to fix the contented of the email you are sending. Google things your spam or a hacking.  I think the best place to find out what would trigger that would be webapps.   This is Not related to your code.  This is related to the email you are sending.